# Kubernetes minions/pods overload external domain controllers by DNS queries

Tags: caching, dns, kubernetes

in kubernetes cluster about 40 pods per one environment and five dev/test/prod environment. So totaly about 200 pods. And I have more than hunderds of thousands DNS request on our Domain controllers(outside of kubernetes) to external DNS FQDNs.  Do you have any best practice how to set up some DNS cache or something inside the kubernetes? Or any other way, how to reduce the DNS queries from kubernetes cluster?

THX

Answer (score 1):

The default Kubernetes internal DNS doesn't support this, however you can [switch to CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) as the provider, which provides you a lot more flexibility.

You can for example use the CoreDNS cache plugin: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/man/coredns-cache.7